# Joomla <jdoc:include type="head" /> not rendering correctly - renders in <body> tag

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla3.0, joomla-template

Recently I was migrating a web page from joomla 1.5 -> joomla 3.2.
The template itself works great.
The content is not displayed because of the  tag.

The written code I have in my index is as:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); // no direct access
JHtml::_('behavior.framework',true);
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'functions.php';
$document = null;
if (isset($this))
    $document = & $this;
$baseUrl = $this->baseurl;
$templateUrl = $baseUrl . '/templates/' . $this->template;

artxComponentWrapper($document);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>"
  xmlns:jdoc="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<head>
  <jdoc:include type="head" name="all" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl; ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl; ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $templateUrl; ?>/css/template.css" media="screen" />

  <!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $templateUrl; ?>/css/template.ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $templateUrl; ?>/script.js"></script>
</head>
...
</html>
```

And this renders as:

```
<html xml:lang="sl-si" lang="sl-si" xmlns:jdoc="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" class="chrome  win">
<head>
  <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
  <jdoc:include type="head" name="all">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/TKMS/templates/tkms_theme/css/template.css" media="screen">
    <!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/TKMS/templates/tkms_theme/css/template.ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/TKMS/templates/tkms_theme/script.js"></script>
    <!--CONTENT-->..
  </jdoc:include>
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix this? I read that this happens because of BOM, but I could not fix it.

Comment: It's rendering as text?  Try jdoc
`<jdoc:include type="head" />`

Comment: Oh the joys of Artisteer. Might be something to do with the function.php file

Comment: @Elin I don't know what you mean?

Comment: @Lodder anything more specific? I will look into the .php file.

Comment: @TristanŠneider - It's hard to tell. Firstly as I have always stayed clear from Artisteer and secondly as I don't know what the functions.php file contains. Try removing `artxComponentWrapper($document);` from the code and see if this fixes the issue. If it does, please copy and paste the code from the functions.php file. If this doesn't fix the issue, I'll make a few changes to your current code to test

Comment: this path seems plain wrong: href="/TKMS/templates/tkms_theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the theme is an Artisteer theme. To solve this issue simply open the .artx theme and export for other joomla version.
If you don't have the .artx file then I cannot help you because I deemed the problem unsolvable.

Answer (score 0):

try to move the

```
  <jdoc:include type="head" name="all">
```

tag into the head-tags, right (You have it in the body). That's at least where it's supposed to be. Not sure if it will actually render, though...

Comment: If you look at his code it is in the head tags ... he doesn't show the body tags but I assume he has them.

Comment: Hi, yes, you're right,  don't know how I missed that.